# Correct syntax fort a matrix in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, matrices

I'm trying to use a matrix in a foootnote, the text compiles but i'm getting this error ''... l.198 ...\sigma}^{i}$ son las matrices de Pauli.}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed...''

Here is my code

```
\footnote{ In Weyl's base ${\gamma}^{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix}
{\mathbb{0}}_{2x2} & {\sigma}^{\mu}\\
{\bar{\sigma}}^{\mu} & {\mathbb{0}}_{2x2}
\end{pmatrix}$ with $ {\sigma}^{\mu}\equiv \{{\mathbb{I}}_{2x2};{\sigma}^{i}\} $ and 
$ {\var{\sigma}}^{\mu} \equiv \{{\mathbb{I}}_{2x2};-{\sigma}^{i}\} $ where 
${\sigma}^{i}$ are the Pauli's matrices.}
```

I get all that i want :

[image]

But i'm still getting the error, how can i solve this?
I'm using this packages

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}
```

Please help.

Comment: It should be `\varsigma` not `\var{\sigma}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no problem having a matrix in a footnote. You just need to use `\varsigma` instead of `\var{\sigma}` in your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bbold}

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{ In Weyl's base ${\gamma}^{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix}
{\mathbb{0}}_{2x2} & {\sigma}^{\mu}\\
{\bar{\sigma}}^{\mu} & {\mathbb{0}}_{2x2}
\end{pmatrix}$ with $ {\sigma}^{\mu}\equiv \{{\mathbb{I}}_{2x2};{\sigma}^{i}\} $ and 
$ \varsigma^{\mu} \equiv \{{\mathbb{I}}_{2x2};-{\sigma}^{i}\} $ where 
${\sigma}^{i}$ are the Pauli's matrices.}

\end{document}
```